# Is this correct or completely wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I've bumped onto the problem described below and I couldn't tell if it is wrong. It looks like it could be correct but it makes no physical sense.

Thank you!
Marcelo!

---

I begin with
$$\frac{p_2}{p_1} = \left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)^{\frac{n}{1-n}\cdot \frac{-1}{-1}} = \left(\frac{T_1}{T_2}\right)^\frac{-n}{n-1}$$
and since $a^{-1} = \frac{1}{a}$,
$$\frac{p_2}{p_1} = \left(\frac{T_2}{T_1}\right)^{\frac{n}{1-n}}$$
but this does not seem correct.

Comment: This one is so gonna get downvoted!!

Comment: I don't see any problem described on the attached image, just a few equations without context.  In any case, you should make your question self-contained rather than dependent on a linked image.  Also, what do you mean by "physical sense"?  (Finally, let me add that the logical symbols "$\implies$" and "$\iff$" seem to be misused in the image.)

Comment: I would believe $p_2/p_1 = (T_2/T_1)^{n/(n-1)}$. I mean, with the first arrow you used two $-1$'s and in the second you pretended that one of them didn't exist.

Comment: Hello. First of all, I'm sorry if I wasn't completely clear about my question. It's my first posted question on this forum. On the first step I multiplied the power by negative 1 on both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I don't see any point in downvoting new users into oblivion.

Comment: You should type it out in LaTeX. Image posts are looked down upon.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. And sorry for messing it up.

Comment: I've edited to change your picture to LaTeX and add a few explanatory lines to the arithmetic.  Please feel free to change anything if I've misinterpreted your intent.

Comment: Hi Strants. Thank you so much for organizing my post. How do I use LaTeX to format it like you did?

Comment: @MarceloFernandes See [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the final step, why have you taken -1 out of the denominator of the power as well? at the end it should be

$$\frac{n}{n-1}$$ not $$\frac{n}{1-n}$$

I don't see the point downvoting things like this so much either. Bit confused why the answers have been downvoted too

Comment: That's correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Physics, we often write
$P^{1-n}T^n = constant$. That is

$$P_1^{1-n}T_1^n = P_2^{1-n}T_2^n $$

or equivalently

$$P_1T_1^{n/(1-n)} = P_2T_2^{n/(1-n)}$$

or equivalently

$${P_2 \over P_1} = \left( {T_1 \over T_2} \right)^{n/(1-n)}$$ or equivalently

$${P_2 \over P_1} = \left( {T_2 \over T_1} \right)^{n/(n-1)}$$

For the last equivalence and the nub of your question, $$\left( {T_1 \over T_2} \right)^{n/(1-n)} = \left(\left( {T_2 \over T_1} \right)^{-1}\right)^{n/(1-n)} = \left( {T_2 \over T_1} \right)^{-n/(1-n)} = \left( {T_2 \over T_1} \right)^{n/(n-1)}$$

Hopefully that much is now clear.

This is the pressure-temperature relationship for an adiabatic process, where $n$ (also written as $\gamma$) is a physical constant for the system known as the heat capacity ratio. The relation $P^{1-n}T^n = constant$ differs from the $P/T = constant$ law you might be thinking of, because in the latter case, work (positive or negative) must be done to change the system that way.

Comment: Downvoters: really?

Comment: Downvoting is like gossip sometimes, it just goes around.  +1 from me for correctly identifying the source of the problem, but it might help to address the mathematical mistake as well.